# Sonata admin bundle: exclude custom admin from global search

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

Within my Symfony 3.4 project, I have 2 custom admins.  Specially created for reporting services.  Those admins do not have specific entities.
For the custom admins, I followed the Symfony recipe:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_view.html

Now, when searching items through the sonata global search, I get a

> "Class does not exist" error in
> vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/Core/search.html.twig.

This error is related to the custom admins.

Is there a solution to exclude these custom admins from the global search or to resolve this error?

Admin:

```
<?php
namespace MainBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class AccessRightsAdmin extends AbstractAdmin 
{
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'accessrights';
    protected $baseRouteName = 'Accessrights';

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->clearExcept(array('list'));
        $collection->add('accesRights', 'accessrights');
    }
}
```

Service

```
services:         
    system.admin.accessrights:
        class: MainBundle\Admin\AccessRightsAdmin
        arguments: [~, ~, MainBundle:AccessRightsAdmin]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: sonata.admin.group.System, label: Accessrights }
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [SonataAdminBundle]]
        public: true
```

Comment: pls post your service definition and your admin class

Comment: Added the code to the post.

Comment: @de_bernie How did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: @de_bernie: Did you find a solution? My workaround is to overwrite the search.html.twig and exclude the specific admin in the if-block.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and I'm going to leave it here in case someone need it.
The solution basically is to override the `search.html.twig` and ignore the admin you want from the search like so:

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block title %}{{ 'title_search_results'|trans({'%query%': query}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}{% endblock %}
{% block breadcrumb %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2 class="page-header">{{ 'title_search_results'|trans({'%query%': query}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</h2>

    {% if query is defined and query is not same as(false) %}
        {% set count = 0 %}
        <div class="row" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".search-box-item" }'>
            {% for group in groups %}
                {% set display = group.roles is empty or is_granted(sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('role_super_admin')) or group.roles|filter(role => is_granted(role))|length > 0 %}

                {% if display %}
                    {% for admin in group.items %}
                        {% set count = count + 1 %}
                        {% if admin.code != 'bundle.admin.admin_to_ignore' %}{# in this line right here add the admin you want to ignore in your search #}
                            {% if admin.hasRoute('create') and admin.hasAccess('create') or admin.hasRoute('list') and admin.hasAccess('list') %}
                                {{ sonata_block_render({
                                    'type': 'sonata.admin.block.search_result'
                                }, {
                                    'query': query,
                                    'admin_code': admin.code,
                                    'page': 0,
                                    'per_page': 10,
                                    'icon': group.icon
                                }) }}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

To override the file you need to put it under the following path:
`app -> Resources -> SonataAdminBundle -> views -> Core -> search.html.twig`

You can also override the template in config_sonata.yml by defining
`sonata_admin.templates.search: YourBundle:Location:Of:search.html.twig`